# In php I have timestamp stored in session or cookie. How To Convert That Timestamp To Date & Time Format?

Tags: php, datetime

Need Solution For Providing Date And Time.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y h:i:s O', '01 Feb 2018 01:01:12 +0530');
echo $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$date = "Thu, 01 Feb 2018 01:01:12 +0530";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Why would someone convert string to timestamp and then create a date object from it when there is `DateTime::createFromFormat`?

Comment: one can do anything @AniketSahrawat altho i agree  :D